# CiviCRM installation on Backdrop; CiviCRM links produce 404. Any thoughts?

Tags: installation, backdrop, shared-hosting

CMS: Backdrop 1.24
CiviCRM: 5.58
PHP: 7.42
MySQL: 5.7.36 etc

I have a Backdrop/CiviCRM installation running without errors on MAMP.

I then tried to install CiviCRM with Backdrop on a live site hosted on a shared server, with a host that is known to support CiviCRM, but I cannot get CiviCRM to work. Installation goes fine, but when I start to try to go through the configuration checklist, I can load each link/form but cannot save any configuration changes I make.

The Backdrop admin menu includes a CiviCRM link, but selecting that does not load CiviCRM properly, no CiviCRM admin menu appears, and I get the following error message:

> Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

CiviCRM tries to load via Ajax this: https://www.[site].com/CiviCRM/ajax/navmenu?code=ZQPw9lWA&locale=en_US&cid=3 and if I open that URL in a fresh tab, the JSON data is there, but the response code is 404. Therefore it doesn't work.

Base URL in CiviCRM.settings.php is https://www.[site].com Have also tried http instead of https and both with and without www.

I have tried with one database and with two (one for Backdrop and one for Civi). Same result.